# spring boot An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

Tags: spring-boot, h2, java-10

Hi I am unable to run my `spring boot + H2 DB` application and getting this error An illegal reflective access operation has occurred . My Java version is `jdk` 10

> And added the dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

> My stacktrace is

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase (file:/D:/Program%20Files/Maven%20Repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.12/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar) to field java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches.localDescs
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-11-14 15:44:29.788  INFO 6896 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
   Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2018-11-14 15:44:29.862 ERROR 6896 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/subhashis/git/MicroservicesCloudBoot/currency-exchange-service/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into employee(id,name) values(1,'a'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(ID)"; SQL statement:
    insert into employee(id,name) values(1,'a') [23505-197]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at com.myapp.CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication.main(CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/subhashis/git/MicroservicesCloudBoot/currency-exchange-service/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into employee(id,name) values(1,'a'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(ID)"; SQL statement:insert into employee(id,name) values(1,'a') [23505-197]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:507) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:240) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:48) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:210) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:93) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:37) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:398) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:355) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:98) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:88) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:434) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1749) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(ID)"; SQL statement:
    insert into employee(id,name) values(1,'a') [23505-197]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
        at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVPrimaryIndex.add(MVPrimaryIndex.java:123) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
        at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.addRow(MVTable.java:732) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
        at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:182) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
        at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:134) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
        at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:102) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
        at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:261) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:233) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:486) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Your error is regarding primary key violation as statement(insert into employee(id,name) values(1,'a')) show you already have id 1 in you table and want to add again 1 into id field which cause this issue.

Comment: Related to the illegal access warning, you can check and report if not already to maintainers of *org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase* to fix it. But yes, that's not the reason for the application failure currently.

Answer (score 1):

The warning in your question title has nothing to do with the exception you're getting.

The warning concerns some things Tomcat Catalina does internally which isn't how it's supposed to be done. They don't intend to fix this however, see http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201809.mbox/%3C6416c4e0-4c85-d76b-a201-6643a0a6421c@apache.org%3E

The exception however is because you're inserting another Employee object with id 1 while you already have one. This seems to be coming from a script on your file system at `C:/Users/subhashis/git/MicroservicesCloudBoot/currency-exchange-service/target/classes/data.sql`. Likely your script prepares some data but the second time you're running it it it fails because you already have that data.